# how to create keystore file, when you have multi apps?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, keystore

How to create keystore of `App2`?

i have two project in following location in windows (visual studio)

```
C:\Users\dan\source\repos\App1
C:\Users\dan\source\repos\App2
```

go to keytool folder

```
 CD C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin
```

create a `keystore` file and it will store inside `debug` folder. But how does it know I want to create `App2` keystore and not `app1`?

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore "C:\Users\dan\source\Keystore\Debug\debug.keystore" -alias AndroidDebugKey -storepass asdf-keypass asdf-keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

Comment: did i missed something?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Normally you wouldn't ever touch the debug.keystore. You either create one per App or create aliases inside your keystore for each App. These keystores should normally only be used for publishing to a store, when debugging it doesn't really matter what keystore you use, no one validates the signature anyways...

Comment: yes its for testing if a plugin works. but i got my answer. once you create keystore file, you can re-sign in visual studio